# In R unzipping files in a directory

Tags: r

1. Downloaded a specdata.zip file from a site into downloads on
   windows.
2. Copied the specdata.zip from downloads folder to a directory called programming
3. Created a new directory on R console using dir.create("specdata")
4. Now,specdata is a new directory listed in programming
5. Rightclicked on specdata.zip file and extracted all the files into specdata directory
6. Now specdata directory has a number of csv files plus an empty folder called specdata
7. I am writing a code and trying to run it
8. errorError in list.files(directory = "C:/Users/Home/Desktop/Coursera/specdata",  :    unused argument
   (directory = "C:/Users/Home/Desktop/programming/specdata")

Can anyone please help me with whats going on?I am totally clueless. I am not even sure whether I have downloaded the files in the correct way. I am a novice programmer. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should narrow your problem down before posting it on here. Literally everything in your post except point 8 is irrelevant.

Comment: So... `?list.files` doesn't take a "directory" argument which is the reason for the error. It does take an argument called "path".

Comment: Konrad : will keep in mind the next time i post.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/4323/extracting-and-listing-files-in-compressed-archives/28663/extract-all-zip-archives-in-a-directory#t=201702242328075050188)